# Connection will be closed due to unrecoverable error com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCProtocol$BAD_MAGIC: Bad header magic: 16030100

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, rad

When I am starting the Websphere Application Server I am facing the following issue:

---

[6/10/14 17:10:11:945 IST] 00000014 IPCConnectorI E   ADMC0074E: Connection will be closed due to unrecoverable error com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCProtocol$BAD_MAGIC: Bad header magic: 16030100
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCProtocol.readMessageHeader(IPCProtocol.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.ready(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

---

Due to this issue my application is not able to invoke the app server.
I am working in java, RAD 7.5, Websphere app server 7.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Im having the same issue using WAS7 and RSA 8.5. Can anyone please offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark. I was having the same issue as you. I am able to get the server started manually. I began searching google using various fragments of the error message.

```
[6/26/14 15:49:19:896 EDT] 0000000a IPCConnectorI E   ADMC0074E: Connection will be closed due to unrecoverable error com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCProtocol$BAD_MAGIC: Bad header magic: 16030100
```

Doing so lead me to an IBM KB article using [stopServer command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_stopserver.html) to stop the server. So I looked into the [startServer command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_startserver.html). By doing so I was able to get the server started again. Can you give it a try?

Using DOS window, navigate to the bin directory for the profile. Mine is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin
```

**Start the Server:**

At the dos prompt, run the command below:

```
startServer server1 -trace -profileName AppSrv01
```

**Command Syntax**

startServer server_name [options]

**Command Switches**

> **-profileName**: The profile to start. If there is only one this can be omitted.
>
> **-trace**: Generates trace information to the log file for debugging purposes.

Hope this helps. It may not resolve the underlying issue but it got my server running again.

You might also start the server in Windows Services.

[image: Screenshot of DOS window running startServer command]

[image: Screenshot of RSA IDE with WAS7 Server restarted as a result of running startServer tool.]

[image: Screenshot of Starting WAS7 Service vai Windows Services]